# How can I immediately reload a folder icon when desktop.ini is changed

Tags: windows, windows-shell, desktop.ini

I've been trying to change folder icon programmatically using changing desktop.ini on the folder. I was able to set an icon, but couldn't change it immediately through changing "IconIndex". The icon was also changed in a few seconds later.

Is there anybody know how to change the icon immediately?

Comment: Take a look SHChangeNotify API and lookup related SO posts.

Comment: I have found a solution about own question. That's what it use **SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings** Win32 function.

Comment: You may write it up as a complete answer below.. That will make it easier for the visitors of this question and it(your answer) will be voted up as well.

Comment: Can't use `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings` in Windows 10. any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered by commenting a reply at my question before. For more convenience, I will write an answer again.

If you want to make any change at an appearance of any folder using Desktop.ini, use some of win32 shell functions. You shouldn't try to edit a Desktop.ini directly. It doesn't get to make any change at an appearance of any folder.

You could get more information of win32 shell functions through the following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776426(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS fcs = {0};
fcs.dwSize = sizeof(SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS);
fcs.dwMask = FCSM_ICONFILE;
fcs.pszIconFile = iconPath;
fcs.cchIconFile = 0;
fcs.iIconIndex = iconIndex;
SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings(&fcs, folderPath, FCS_FORCEWRITE);
```

Comment: I get an error: `'SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS' was not declared in this scope`. any workaround? same goes for `'SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings' was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure works well for me (on Windows 7):

1. Change desktop.ini file
2. Issue SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_DELETE,SHCNF_PATH,"path_to/desktop.ini",0);
3. Folder ico will be refreshed

Remember to include Shlobj.h

Comment: Wrong include. It should be Shlwapi.h.

Comment: NO it doesn't work at all. 5 hour in computer during the night works as mirage

Comment: Any Idea How to refresh folder icons after desktop.ini change? The SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings is not suported since XP windows.